# I need help writing the right constraint syntax in annotation form for validating array of objects

Tags: php, symfony, validation, constraints, assert

I'm using Symfony 5. In my app, I have a react app that posts entity data to the server. Then on the server side, I'll json_decode the data into an object, then validate and persist it to the database. I use DTO object instead of the entity class to handle the constraint. The problem came when writing the constraint to handle array of objects.

my data object structure

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "john",
    images: [
      { id: 1,   img_name: "hello" },
      { id: 2,   img_name: "world" }
    ]
}
```

DTO file

```
class PersonDTO {

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Type("integer")
     */
    public $id    

    /**
     * @Assert\All({
     *     @Assert\Collection(
     *         fields = {
     *             "id" = @Assert\Type("integer")
     *         }
     */
    public $images
}
```

controller

```
public function index(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator) 
{
    $jsonData = $request->getContent();
    $dataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

    $personDTO = new PersonDTO();
    $personDTO->id = $dataObject->id;
    $personDTO->images = $dataObject->images

    $errors = $validator->validate($personDTO);
}
```

I have followed the Symfony documentation on handling the array of object, but it doesn't work. The validation failed on the `images` array with the message `Object(App\DTO\PersonDTO).images[0]: This value should be of type array|(Traversable&ArrayAccess).`

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found the problem. The Symfony validation can only validate array, not object. So to validate array of object, I'll need to convert it to array of arrays.

```
public function index(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator) 
{
    // converting from json string
    $dataArray = json_decode($json, true);

    // converting from object
    $dataArray = json_decode(json_encode(dataObject), true);
}
```

After that just pass the value to the DTO object for validation

```
$personDTO = new PersonDTO();
$personDTO->id= $dataArray['id']
$personDTO->images = $dataArray['images']

$errors = $validator->validate($personDTO);
```

Ultimately I make this into a static function in the DTO class to make the controller cleaner.

```
// PersonDTO class
public static function fromJson(string $json): self
    {
        $PersonDTO = new self();
        $dataArray = json_decode($json, true);

        $PersonDTO ->id = $dataArray['id'];
        $PersonDTO ->images = $dataArray['images'];        
        return $PersonDTO ;
    }

// controller
$personDTO = PersonDTO::fromJson($jsonData);
$errors = $validator->validate($PersonDTO );
```